# Greatest lower bound of the set : $\{(e^n + 2^n)^\frac1n\ | \; n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital, limsup-and-liminf

Find the greatest lower bound of the set :
$\{(e^n  + 2^n)^\frac1n \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

I will find the limit of  $a_n := (e^n  + 2^n)^\frac1n $ which if exists, must equal the greatest lower bound ($\liminf$)
$$
(e^n  + 2^n)^\frac1n 
= e\left(1+\left(\frac2e\right)^n\right)^{\frac1n}
\to e
$$ 
So the required answer is $e$? is this correct?

Comment: To prove that the limit exists, you also need to specify that the sequence is monotone decreasing, and that it is bounded from below. Using basic inequalities you can show that it is bounded below by either $e$ or $2$, for instance. But after you have proved the limit exists, you are absolutely correct to use the result you did and determine that it is $e$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct. You might also want to add that $(e^n + 2^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is strictly decreasing $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Technical question: If the first two expressions are equal, why does [WolframAlpha "disagree"](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(e%5En++%2B+2%5En)%5E(1%2Fn)+-+e(1%2B(2%2Fe)%5En)%5E(1%2Fn)+%3D+0%3F) ?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik It's not disagreeing, the error (the y axis) is in 10^-16, so close to zero, so it is zero modulo comp sci shenanigans.